# .NET Core 3.1 role based authorization fails, getting 403 exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to use Microsoft Identity library to do a role base authorization and I am failing.

- I can authenticate the user
- I see the role that user is belonging to matches the Role I have on the controller
- When I go to that controller I get 403 Forbidden error

I don't know how to debug it further.

Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>(opt => opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true)
    .AddRoles<UserRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EntityDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var jwtSetting = _configuration
    .GetSection("JwtSettings")
    .Get<JwtSettings>();

services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(config =>
    {
        config.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        config.SaveToken = true;

        config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = jwtSetting.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = jwtSetting.Audience,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSetting.Key))
        };
    });
```

My Controller with a role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Internal")]
[ApiController]
[Route("Api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : BasicCrudController<User>
{
     // Stuff here ...
}
```

[Repo url](https://github.com/amir734jj/contractor-finder-api/)

Comment: Can you share the code for services.addauthorization. Did you create policy?

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera I put the link to repo in the question

Comment: It's going to 404 

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera Please try again. I'm not sure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add a claim of type *ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType* into jwt token for its role

Comment: can you write the example code for it? i am not sure how it needs to look